# Weight of geographical back links to other links

Tags: seo, search-engines, local-seo

I know that back links are a big deal when it comes to ranking in the search engines, but do links originating from the same country (as to where you want your results to be displayed) have more weight than links originating from outside of the country where you want your results to be displayed? Or doesn't it really matter?

I have a site, for this example, I will say that it is in the UK. So my URL looks like this:

```
www.example.co.uk
```

I would prefer that my site be displayed in search results to people that are searching from the UK, I don't mind if it is outside of the UK, but UK would be my first choice. So if someone is searching for a specific food recipe from some where in the UK, and I have a matching recipe then I would like my recipe to be displayed in the search results.

To be able to be more prominent in the search results to users in the UK, do I need to get back links from other sites in the UK? Or doesn't it matter? Can I get back links from Australia, America, and other countries?

How important are links that originate from the same country as to links that originate in other countries. If I get most of my back links from other countries outside of the UK would I be less prominent in UK search results?

I don't have a local business, it's just a blog. I would just like my results to display first in my country and then to a international audience.

Answer (score 1):

Links on themself are all the same. What makes them different is their relevance. And their relevance make users clicking on them and making something after click.

So, lets suppose, your site has relevant content for users from UK. If a link to your site is placed on the site from USA, a USA visitor clicks on it, goes to your site and realizes, it is only relevant for UK visitors. The USA visitor clicks back and this is not good user metric, which your site was earning there.

Yes, location of sites, linking to your site is important, but not directly - there is no rule like "links from USA site to UK site are bad".

But, if another location means less relevance - then yes, they will be less useful, not useful, ...bad...? No, maybe not bad as harmful, but without any additional value and with negative user metrics.